# Is there a way in VerneMQ to add delay between sending messages to different topics one by one?

Tags: mqtt, iot, mqtt-vernemq

I want to be able to send a message eg "New Ride" to Topic 1, Topic 2, and Topic 3 one by one with a delay of lets say 3 seconds in between them. Is there a way in VerneMQ inbuilt that can deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

No, brokers will not add delay to messages, if you want a delay you need to introduce it yourself in the publishing client.